# Universal Windows App Show Page As Dialog

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, wfp

I am trying to display a page as a dialog in Universal Window App (Windows 10).

In WFP, there is this ShowDialog to call on Window:

```
var msgBox = new MessageWindow();
msgBox.Owner = App.Current.MainWindow;
msgBox.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
msgBox.SetMessage(message, messageCategory);
msgBox.ShowDialog();
```

How do I do something like that in Universal Window App (Windows 10)?

Here is a [Sample Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq0JN.png) of how it looks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no exact same MessageWindow in UWP. It depends on what you want to do with the dialog.

In UWP, there are many options we can choose to display a popup/dialog to show information or require user interaction.

Dialog:

- [MessageDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx)
- [ContentDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx)

Lightweight Control:

- [Flyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout.aspx)
- [MenuFlyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyout.aspx)
- [ToolTip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltip.aspx)

If above cannot meet your requirement, try [Popup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) which gives you more flexibility.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response.  
I decided to go with the ContentDialog route.  

We are trying to port to UWP and the ContenDialog would keep the same structure.

Comment: Thank you @Alan.
I used PopUp to show an image tag.

I added image in a usercontrol. this usercontrol was child of popup. and i just controlled isOpen of popup and enabled the IsLightDismissEnabled property.

It's beautiful.



Now I have to find a way to refresh the image tag after every 3 seconds. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

To show a page as a dialog box its probably something like this:

```
var D = new ContentDialog {
    Title = "MyPage",
    Content = new MyUserControl()
};

var T = D.ShowAsync();
```

Most examples of ContentDialog show Content set to a string, however Content can be set to any UIElement including a UserControl.

In above example, place your page inside of a UserControl:

```
<UserControl …>
    <StackPanel>
         …
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

You get the idea...